# Factor theorem applied to an "extreme" example

Tags: polynomials

The roots of the polynomial $f(x) = - x^4$ are $0$ with a multiplicity of $4$.

How can I apply the factor theorem:

$$f(x) = (x-0)(x-0)(x-0)(x-0)$$

correctly as to account for the minus sign?

I know the specific example is a bit nonsensical because of all the zeros, but it is about the theorem, and the apparent difficulty in going from $-x^4$ to $(x - a)$ factors.

Comment: The leading coefficient comes outside, as $-1$. So it is $-1(x-0)^4$ if you wish.

Comment: Let's say for the sake of simplicity, in your case, the factor theorem says: you have $4$ roots $r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4$ and this is a polynomial of degree $4$, so $f(x) = \lambda (x - r_1)(x - r_2)(x - r_3)(x - r_4)$, in fact $r_1 = r_2 = r_3 = r_4 = 0$ in your case so that $f(x) = \lambda (x - 0)^4 = \lambda x^4$, finally $\lambda = -1$ by looking at your original $f$.

Comment: @Raito. Sure, but this lambda is not part of the theorem... How did it appear?

Comment: Quote the specific theorem, it will clarify itself. Your expression is not what the theorem says, it does not account for multiplicity to start with.

Comment: @justquestions If you apply the factor theorem on your example as much as there are roots, you'll end up with $f(x) = x^4 g(x)$ with $g$ a certain function of $x$, can $g$ be something else than $g : x \mapsto -1$ ? More generally, if you use factor theorem as much as there are roots, let's say $n$, you'll end up with $f(x) = (X - r_1)\ldots(X - r_n)g(x)$ with $(r_1, \ldots, r_n)$ your roots, as $f$ has at most $n$ roots (in our case, exactly $n$ roots), $g$ must be a constant, so a certain $\lambda$ (over a certain field, I guess $\mathbb{R}$ here.)

Comment: @Raito That is it! thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The factor theorem (over a field) says that $x=c$ is a root of $f(x)$ if and only if $f(x) = (x-c)g(x)$ for some polynomial $g(x)$.  Your minus sign is inside $g(x)$.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. However, what happens when you "unveil" the magic within g(x)? Then (see comments above), there is a lambda that appears out of thin air. I want to understand what I am missing in that lambda creation that is not in the FT.

Comment: Works for Rings, as in the specific instance above. +1 for the statement.

Comment: constants are polynomials.  No problem having a $\lambda$ there.